# How to make two functions of regex compatible?

Tags: jquery, regex

The code below is to convert url into clickable link and the other one is to add style to smiley shortcodes. The problem is that the link is not displayed properly when I use the shortcode ":/". It's because :/ is also present on the http://... Please help me fix it.

```js
$(".test1").html(function(i, html) {
  buildhtml = html
  .replace(/(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig,"<a href='$1'>$2</a>")
  .replace(/(:\)|:\/|:\D)/ig,"<div class='icon'>$1</div>");
  return buildhtml;
});
```

```css
.icon {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
:) :D :/
    
http://link.com
</div>
```

Comment: You need to combine the two patterns in one and to use a callback function as replacement. use capture groups to differentiate the two branches.

Comment: whew my knowledge is far from that :(

Comment: Don't worry, it's very simple.

Comment: The thing is I only knew css... I'm trying to find a solution but it's almost one day past and can't make it work yet... I appreciate it if somebody here will extend a help...

Answer (score 2):

To make a general answer:

You have two patterns with two replacement strings, but the second pattern matches parts that the first pattern matches too, and you want to avoid this.

So the way is to use this pattern:

```
/(pattern1)|pattern2/g
```

Where `(...)` delimits the capture group 1 and `|` is the logical operator `OR`

This avoid overlapping matches, and has the advantage to parse the string only once.

The `String.prototype.replace` method can take a function as replacement:

```
mystr = mystr.replace(/(pattern1)|pattern2/g, function (m, g1, g2) {
    return (g1) ? 'repla' + g1 + 'cem' + g2 + 'ent1'
                : 'repla' + m + 'cement2';
});
```

Where `m` is the full match and `gn` are the capture groups.

```
return (g1) ? 'repla' + g1 + 'cem' + g2 + 'ent1'
            : 'repla' + m + 'cement2';
```

is a shortcut for:

```
if (g1) { // g1 is only defined when pattern1 succeeds
    return 'repla' + g1 + 'cem' + g2 + 'ent1';
} else {
    return 'repla' + m + 'cement2';
}
```

The full working code:

The pattern is:

```
/(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)|(:\)|:\/|:\D)/ig
```

Since the pattern 1 was already surrounded by parens, there is no need to put it in a capture group.

The pattern can be a little simplified to:

```
/(https?:\/\/([-\w.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)|:[)D\/]/ig
```

With your code:

```
$(".test1").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(
        /(https?:\/\/([-\w.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)|:[)D\/]/ig,
        function (m, g1, g2) {
            return (g1) ? '<a href="' + g1 + '">' + g2 + '</a>'
                        : '<div class="icon">' + m + '</div>';
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, though I really can't understand that .. I've already created various functions like bad word filtering, displaying video and image.. using that format. I'm happy it worked even though I dont have knowlege about jquery.  The only problem is the one I mentioned above... maybe there is a solution without breaking the code format.

Comment: Hi Sir, the link still breaks.

Comment: it worked in fiddle but not in jsbin :D . I will try to add my other functions by following your format, hope u can still give advice after I show you :)